# How to control an office 2010 PowerPoint presentation remotely using an android application?

Tags: java, android, powerpoint

I want to write an Android remote control application that allows people to navigate back and forth on a PowerPoint slideshow presentation in Microsoft Office (preferably 2007/2010) on my PC. In this case, I have to make a small PowerPoint navigation client on the Android, and also I have create a PC server to access Microsoft Office PowerPoint and manipulate its slideshow. I know it is possible for a java application to gain access to Microsoft Office PowerPoint's slideshow. Some applications for Android are already made (Gmote 2.0 and such) and they can be used to navigate PowerPoint slideshows.
Is there any extension or any library that can be used to gain access to Microsoft Office PowerPoint? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just write the server side code to inject keyboard events (arrow keys).  Presuming the slide show is currently running, that should be sufficient.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i didn't know it could be like that :)

Answer (score 3):

what I did was:

1. I use a .NET #C Client on the Windows Side and
2. A Java Servlet and XMLRPC Web App running on a Tomcat ("in the middle").
3. And of course a Android Client as the controler

My C# Client creates a persistent HTTP Connection to a Servlet. And the Android App is sending short HTTP GET Requests to the TomCat, stuff like goto3 or next (the request has also a kind of a Presentation ID as parameter). The Comands from the Android Device are dispatched to the previously opened Persistent HTTP Connection from the .NET Client.

In The .NET Client I use a local installed PowerPoint as an ActiveX/OLE Control. You can do pretty much everything programatically in over c# that is possible to do "by hand". Open a .ppt(x), start the SlideShow, control the Slideshow and of course it is also possible to edit the slides content. You can find a lot of examples by googling for Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint

I pair the .NET Client with the Android Phone by using a Generated QR Code. That QR Code I show in a generated PowerPoint Slide. All Work around the QR Code (C# and Android) is done by using code from the ZXing (Zebra Crossing) Project.

You can try it out, Instructions and Downloads are [here](http://www.thomas-lankes.de/fonprompt/). The App is called FonPrompt and can be found in Google Play.